How can I figure out why using the arrow keys selecting text in VSCode?
I'm the sort of person who switches around among a lot of editors, and tweaks various things to get them to my liking.  While using VSCode to edit a file today (a YAML file, if it matters, but I've noticed it in all the other file types I tried just now) that when I use the arrow keys to move my cursor, it selects text!  This is SUCH an annoying setting that I assume I would have noticed it before now if it had been happening for months or years - but I switch around which editor I use so frequently that it's entirely possible I would not have noticed it for weeks.
So, I assume I added an extension or changed some seemingly unrelated setting at some point which caused this behavior to start. My problem is - how do I find what to change back?  I had to do things to make vscode even marginally usable (some default behaviors for vscode - looking at you, basic emacs keybindings -is different between linux and mac versions, for example - wtf? That seems like a poor design decision to have them different) and one of the most annoying things is that it's really hard to figure out "what did I change?" amidst the twisty passages of the VSCode settings.
So, I'd love one of two things: either a suggestion about how to disable the particular behavior (using the arrow keys causes text to be selected) OR a usable, general method for finding settings of this nature so I can fix what is almost certainly (I hope) something that I did to myself here.

What do you see when you troubleshoot your keybindings? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post. Include also the top section of the file opened by running Developer: Inspect Key Mappings in the command palette and all following text that is related to the keys of interest.

The worst of all worlds: by the time I found the cycles to start debugging this actively (and not having used VScode on this (Linux) computer in the meanwhile), the problem mysteriously disappeared.  :/
The hint about troubleshooting keybindings is exactly what I was looking for, though - should this problem recur, I'll start there.

For things inside the domain of VS Code, run keyboard troubleshooting (Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting).
For things outside of VS Code, use whatever is available to you. Check if the issue reproduces in any other application- especially Chromium-based ones. If you use a keyboard mapping tool, check if it has a debug/spy tool builtin. If you did system-level remapping, use a system keyboard event logging tool (Ex. xev for X11).
